# Deleting cookies created from another web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I would like to know if there is any way to delete cookies created by some other external application using c# code.Say website www.a1.com created a cookie by name AuthToken. And I would like to write a program in a aspx page in another website www.a2.com to delete that cookie. These two websites are related but they serve different purpose. We have complete control on these two web sites.

Comment: If you control both sites, you might be able to use something like iframe to load a page from a1.com while the host is on a2.com and have the a1.com page clear your cookie

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that's not how cookies work. There isn't cross-origin cookie sharing/manipulation.

One option is to use CORS on `a1` and implement an AJAX request that deletes the cookie that is called from `a2`.